# How to get user by uid in views_php?

Tags: views

i am using the [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module and i need to get the user by his uid to read out some properties to build a filter. (It is not the currently logged-in user!).
Is there some drupal function like this ?

```
$myuser = drupal_get_user_by_uid(uid);
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is :

```
$user=user_load($uid);
$username=$user->name;
```

Comment: Good you're a quick learner.

Comment: i try my best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is

[user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7)

> Loads a user object.

[user_load_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7)

> Load multiple users based on certain conditions.